# Compute $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{\cos x + 1 - x^2}{(1 + x\sin x)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

**Problem :**

Compute $$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{\cos x + 1 - x^2}{(1 + x\sin x)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

---

My Attempt :

The original problem is compute integral under $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and since an integrand is even, I manipulated '$-\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$' to '$0$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$'.

And I tried sub $x = \sin t$ to use a relation $\cos x = \sqrt{1 - \sin^2x}$.

But It didnt give me any improvement because I can't do anything after sub.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I think what you meant was that the integrand was even, right?

Comment: @doobdood yes the 'odd' was a typo, sorry.